# Run Method after User Stops Typing in TextArea React

Tags: reactjs

I have a `textarea` component that has an `onChange` attribute.

I want to make some function that will console log the `textarea` value when the user stops typing in the `textarea`. One idea I had would be to make a function that saves after 1 second of waiting, but the timer restarts when it is called.

So like this:

```
function save() {
    // wait for one second (this resets if save() is called again)
    // console.log(textarea.value)
}
```

How could I do something like this?

Comment: What you're asking for is a `debounce` method. Libraries like lodash, underscore have one.

Comment: @dwjohnston I will give it a shot - very new to react though so it is a bit hard to understand at first glance.